# What is effective, non-toxic method to clean vomit from a carpet?

Tags: cleaning

Currently, we use a brand name carpet cleaner/stain remover after cleaning up the general mess with a wet cloth.

I'm wondering if there's a natural, low-cost alternative to cleaning up such messes that:

- Treats stains, if there's a risk
- Treats the smell
- Kills any bacteria/viruses (if that's what caused it)
- Is safe for children

My son already knows how to twist the nozzle on spray bottles to open them and spray them, so it'd be ideal if whatever we kept in a spray bottle wasn't a poison/exposure risk for children.

While I'm mostly interested in carpet, because it can't be thrown into the washer/dryer, I would be grateful for solutions to cleaning non-removable parts of the car/car seat. Seat belts, in particular, have been resistant to most of our cleaners.

Multi-step methods are fine, but I'd prefer something that doesn't require more than 5-10 minutes of time to complete. Usually when these incidents occur we're already occupied, and don't have much time to spare.

But, long-term soaking techniques are acceptable if they're provided *after* a quicker solution that does a good enough job until the soaking can be accomplished.

Note: At this time we own a carpet cleaner, so alternative machine-safe carpet cleaner solutions would be valid. However, we don't have and can't currently afford a steam cleaner (because we bought the carpet cleaner), so steam cleaning isn't a viable solution for us.

Comment: While vomit is a common parenting problem, is this possibly a better fit for LifeHacks? (I sort of hope not, I want to see the answers...!)

Comment: @Erica Possibly, but I want chemicals specifically for being safe around children, not for being green. I'll edit that in to reflect it. I'm definitely looking for answers from a parenting perspective.

Comment: How about "remove the carpet and instead use hardwood floors"? :)

Comment: @Joe I dislike hardwood floors for a number of reasons. But, we're also renters and we're technically living in poverty, so any remodeling is off the table. Interesting fact I just looked up, [1/3rd of US residents are renters](https://nmhc.org/Content.aspx?id=4708).

Comment: It wasn't a particularly serious comment, given the smiley. :)

Comment: @Joe I know, but I'm hoping it may discourage it as a serious answer from others. ;)

Comment: I know cross-posting isn't encouraged, but this would be suitable for lifehacks.se as well i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution I've seen is baking soda.  It is a fairly effective odor neutralizer.  After the "chunks" have been removed, liberally cover with baking soda, let it sit for a bit, then wash out with water.

Afterwards (and after thoroughly rinsing), if stains persist a solution of vinegar and dishwashing soap plus water seems to be recommended; I've never done this myself.  See [this article](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/home/cleaning/tips/a12467/stains-vomit-may07/) and many like it on the internet for an explanation of this process.

Another common tool is "pet" carpet powders, which are basically enzyme based cleaners.  Many are non-toxic.  They help break down the proteins in the mess, which helps with the stain.